# ReadAsArray() equivalent in C

Tags: gdal, image, array, c

I'm new with GDAL ... and I'm trying to write some code where I have to read a .raw image and store it as an array of 32-bit floats. It seems that it is easy with python, I just have to use:

```
array = image.ReadAsArray().asType(float32)
```

But What I'm trying to know is if there is any way to have the same thing with the C API.

Answer (score 2):

From the [GDAL API tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html#gdal_tutorial_read):

> There are a few ways to read raster data, but the most common is via the [GDALRasterBand::RasterIO()](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a30786c81246455321e96d73047b8edf1) method